# How to change evm token decimals?

Tags: frontier, evm

native token of my chain has 12 decimals,now i have integrated EVM functionality into my chain, is there any way by which i can change evm decimals from 18 to 12 as i don't want to change my native token decimals???

Answer (score 3):

You should, and I recommend changing your native token decimals. Otherwise, you need a converter.

Then, I have a question.

Why do you need EVM? This will break almost every existing thing (such as smart contract). EVM's goal is to mock Ethereum and re-use the existing infrastructures. And the third-party developers will be so confused while developing base on your chain.

---

Here https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-common/blob/6a9392cfb9fe2c99b1c2b47d0c36125d61991bb7/frame/dvm/ethereum/src/adapter.rs#L136.

Darwinia has been running for over 2 years.
Finally, we give up on maintaining this.
We change the decimal to 18.
So, that's my suggestion.

Comment: Xavier thanks for your response , we want EVM functionality in our chain, and its been more than 1 yr our chain is live so we want to add EVM functionality. we want a solution for token decimals as our native token has 12 decimals.can you tell me something about converter.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the decimals of your native token you have to modify your chain_spec.rs file.
Import in the `node/Cargo.toml` sc-chain-spec

```
[dependencies.sc-chain-spec] 
branch = 'master'
git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate"
```

And in the function development_config() or local_testnet_config() add your properties:

```
let mut properties = sc_chain_spec::Properties::new();
properties.insert("tokenDecimals".into(), 12.into());
```

And finally add in properties: of the from_genesis call:

```
// Properties
Some(properties),
```

See an example in the [Parachain Template Node](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/blob/main/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L66)

Comment: alex thanks for your response but i don't need this.